# Selenium IDE table and source tab

Tags: selenium-ide

Good Day!

I have installed Selenium IDE here: https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/
Upon opening the application, I was able to record the actions that are made on the browser, however I cannot see where I can view the codes generated by those action so I can export them.

Appreciate any help.
[Image showing that there is no Table or Source Tab on the Selenium that I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMvCw.png)

Comment: There are no actions showing in your screenshot.. why do you think you successfully recorded any actions?